# creating a session in react native with laravel

Tags: laravel, react-native

i am new to both react native and larvel i have created a api for registration of users and is able to register the users
what i want is now to create a session after each registertion is complted so user can use the app
i am not sure whether i must be doing that in larvel or react native

this is my curret code in react native

```
   axios
      .post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/details', Data56)

      .then(res => {
        props.navigation.navigate('Home_scrren', {data: Data56})
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
```

i am looking for something like this

```
 localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
```

but as i a bigenner in larvel i am also not able to create a tokon

Answer (score 0):

Use Passport or sanctrum, It automatically generate a token after user authentication and return with the response.

learn more from the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#main-content

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#main-content